# Postgres: update column by id referenced in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 2 tables and I am attempting to change the value of a particular column based on extracting the row id from another table whose column matches a particular value.

Table 1 (cc_show) contains the column (background_color) and I want to change this value to a fixed value (ff0000) if Table 2 (cc_show_instances) column 'record' OR column 'rebroadcast' is equal to 1.

Furthermore, for all columns in Table 2 (cc_show_instances) whose 'record' OR 'rebroadcast' columns are not equal to 1, I would like to change the corresponding id in Table 1 to 0000ff.

I can search Table 2 (cc_show_instances) for all the positive results with the following command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT show_id 
FROM cc_show_instances 
WHERE rebroadcast = 1 
OR record = 1
```

I tried the putting this as a SELECT contained in the WHERE option as follows:

```
UPDATE cc_show 
   SET background_color = 'ff0000' 
WHERE id = (SELECT DISTINCT show_id 
            FROM cc_show_instances 
            WHERE rebroadcast = 1 OR record = 1);
```

but this returns the error:

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Which I assume is because it is not iterating through the results. How can I achieve the desired results?

Comment: change `=` to `IN` eg. `..WHERE id IN (SELECT..`

Answer (score 1):

You have been told about `IN` in the comments.
Better yet, join to the second table in a [`FROM` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html). That's a bit shorter and `IN` does not scale as well for big sets (at least in my tests in Postgres 8.4 - 9.2).

```
UPDATE cc_show s
SET    background_color = 'ff0000'
FROM   cc_show_instances si
WHERE  1 IN (si.rebroadcast, si.record)  -- IN is good for small sets
AND    s.id = si.show_id;
```